# Will not wear out of the flesh

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is a phrase

> What is bred in the bone will not **wear out** of the flesh.

What is the meaning of wear out in this context?

Answer (score 2):

This is an unusual version of this proverb.  Apparently the [more common version](https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095525826) is:

> What is bred in the bone will **come out** in the flesh.

or

> What is bred in the bone will **not come out of** the flesh.

Which is to say, "lifelong habits or inherited characteristics cannot be concealed."

The use in your example is possibly based on an archaic used of "wear out" to mean "like an article of clothing worn *outside* the body".

> That which is deeply ingrained in one's character will be worn (like clothing) for everyone to see.

This is probably related to other expressions about how it is impossible to avoid inherited characteristics:

> The apple does not fall far from the tree
>
> Blood will tell
>
> The tiger can not change his stripes

and others.

(Edit)  It's also possible that "wear out" is an archaic use to mean something like the modern "get [something] out", as in

> You can't **get out** of the flesh what is bred in the bone.

Comment: It's so interesting that there's two forms of the saying, both with the same basic meaning, yet one is the negation of the other. I'd say your interpretation of "wear out" is fitting for the positive form of the sentence, but not OP's negative one, where I'd guess "will not wear out" is the normal modern meaning "will not pale/weaken/wash out (with time)".

Comment: @Amadan  Apparently the saying was originally in the negative:  **It will not out of the fleshe, that's bred in the bone**  (from 1546, but probably much older) where "out" is an archaic use to mean "can't get [something] out of", like a tough stain.  I suppose later generations felt the need to clarify,  or it's the typical game of Telephone where things are slowly altered as they pass from ear to ear.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense (with “out” rather than “wear out”).